# How do you push a JSON object key and values to Firebase?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, firebase

I am trying to save AJAX object data in variables in order to push them into my Firebase.

Upon a successful AJAX request, I have this function:

```
success: function(brews){
//debugger

      console.log(brews);

      window.brewSearch1 = brews;
      console.log(window.brewSearch1); // Saving the results objects
      console.log(brews.data[0].name);
      console.log(window.brewSearch1.data[0].name);

      for (var i = 0; i < brews.data.length; i++){

        console.log(brews.data[i].name);
        window.beersByNames = brews.data[i].name;
        window.beersByNamesWithDescriptions = brews.data[i].description;
        console.log(window.beersByNames);
        console.log(window.beersByNamesWithDescriptions);

      //Store to Firebase
      myDataRef.push({name: beersByNames_FB, text: brews.data[i].name}); 
      myDataRef.push({name: beersByNamesWithDescriptions_FB, text: brews.data[i].description});  //Store Objects

      }
  },
```

I am having a problem getting the object data to push into Firebase.

Should I use myDataRef.push().set({ })?

Comment: What is the problem? Is there an error message? Aso: what's in `brews`? Can you add the JSON for that to your question (you can get it with `console.log(JSON.stringify(brews,null,'  ')`)?

Comment: It is a JSON object with numerous objects providing data. I can console.log it and it verifies that data is being accessed.